# Error creating jtds connection

Tags: java, sql-server, locale, jtds

Using jtds 1.2.5 I have this error when I stablish a connection: "No message resource found for message property prop.sokeepalive"

At first, I was using 1.2.2 version but I have this error message. "Error getting jdbc connection: The USE database statement failed because the database collation Serbian_Latin_100_CI_AS is not recognized by older client drivers. Try upgrading the client operating system or applying a service update to the database client software, or use a different collation. See SQL Server Books Online for more information on changing collations."

As solution, I tried to use 1.2.5 version getting the error mentioned at the beggining.

I was looking for hints in jtds documentation, but I can not resolve the problem.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running client JVM with `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Duser.country=US` options.
This would switch to everywhere-supported US locale.

Maybe this easy solution would be acceptable in your case.
At least, this would reveal if the problem is in lack of i18n messages resource bundle for current locale in jtds package, as I guess.

**Update**

Try to just copy `jtds.jar/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Messages.properties` and add it to classpath or right inside jtds.jar as `net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Messages_sr_RS.properties`.

Some explaining links:

[Message bundle choosing process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.util.ResourceBundle.Control%29)

[net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Messages source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Messages.java#Messages.loadResourceBundle%28%29)

http://www.localeplanet.com/java/sr-RS/

**Update 2**

Message bundle choosing process should switch to default provided resource anyway.
My second guess is that Messages.properties of jtds package gets eclipsed by some unrelated file with the same name.
Check your classpath.

You should be able to debug `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Messages` in order to find what's happening on for sure.

Comment: Hi Vadzim, this is not a valid option for my customer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried other jtds versions. from 1.2.2 yo 1.3.1 (recompiled to java 1.6) and all of them has the same error.

"Error getting jdbc connection: The USE database statement failed because the database collation Serbian_Latin_100_CI_AS is not recognized by older client drivers. Try upgrading the client operating system or applying a service update to the database client software, or use a different collation. See SQL Server Books Online for more information on changing collations."

Perhaps jdts does not support this collation.